# Automatically add braces in Texworks

Tags: auto-completion

I tend to use Texshop in my macbook. I like it because of simplicity, I don't need a big IDE, and I feel at home with it. However at my office I use a Linux computer. I also like to keep things simple and use an editor that looks/behaves as much as possible as Texshop, because my fingers get confused when typing quickly if things are too different.

In Texshop, braces are added automatically after typing $_$ or $^$, a feature which I have learned to love. Is there a way to make that happen as well in Texworks? I can't find any option at all.